# Why does my PowerShell belief it's a Cygwin terminal?

Tags: powershell, cygwin, console, python3

Lately I discovered that colorama* does not work as intended. It does not convert ANSI escape sequences into WinAPI calls to change the PoSh console text colors. I noticed that it works correct in an old cmd console but not in PowerShell.

I also noticed that colorama works as intended if I call the init function with the convert parameter: `colorama.init(convert=True)`. Normally, colorama automatically recognizes Windows consoles.

To do so, colorama tests for a environment variable named `TERM`. My PowerShell returns `cygwin`!

How can I find **the** Cygwin installation that sets this variable?

Notes:

- `TERM` is not set in cmd consoles
- I never installed a standalone Cygwin, but many of my installed tools bring their own Cygwin folders/installations (> 6)
- deinstalling these tools is no option

In a current workound, I delete env:TERM in each PS session.

---

- colorama is a console wrapper written in/for Python to enable colored text outputs on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Does TERM show up in the environment variable lists in the Windows GUI? If so, that's most likely where it's coming from each time you start PS.

Comment: No it's not in the environment variables window. Otherwise it would be set on cmd and PoSh sessions. There is also no other variable hinting to a paticular cygwin installation.

Comment: I search my registry, but there is no `TERM` or `cygwin` value declared. So it should be set by an script.